# Block only displaying part of content?

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a little problem and I have no idea what is going on.

I have a block in my footer that is only displaying say 100 characters. Then it just gets cut off. Yet on my old server the entire block got displayed. The only difference is PHP version.

Is there something that I can look at that would cause a block to only partially render?

Comment: What input filter does that block use?

Comment: full_html is the input filter.

Comment: Check in the database if the block content has been migrated completely. Also make sure that the filter settings are setup properly - sometimes you can get to the problem by analyzing where exactly does the content is cut.